# Stability criterion for leapfrog in relativistic physics.

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics

I am doing a 2D MD simulations of charge carriers in graphene using the [Leapfrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) algorithm. I am trying to prove that, in some specific cases (when distance between particles is small), the method is unstable.

The Hamiltonian is given as $H =  |\vec{p_{1}}| + |\vec{p_2}| - \frac{\alpha}{r_{12}}$. With $p$ the momentums, $\alpha$ some numerical constant and $r_{12}$ some constants.

The leapfrog iteration would be:

$$
\vec{p_i} \to \vec{p_i} - 0.5 \Delta t \frac{\alpha}{r_{ij}^2} \hat{r_{ij}}\\
\vec{x_i} \to \vec{x_i} + \Delta t \hat{p_i} \\
\vec{p_i} \to \vec{p_i} - 0.5 \Delta t \frac{\alpha}{r_{ij}^2} \hat{r_{ij}}
$$

where the vectors with hat's are the direction vectors. 
I expect the stability to break down when $r_{ij}$ gets small. Yet, I tried using analysis from [this (page 7 onward)](http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/115/leapfrog.pdf) source and it didn't really help.

Also, a different way to derive leapfrog is to define coordinate shift operators $L_p$ and $L_r$ that move $p \to p +\Delta p$ and $x \to x + \Delta x$. Then the differential equation can be written as:
$$
f(p(t), r(t)) = \exp\left(t (L_p + L_r) \right) f(p(0), r(0)).
$$
Using Trotter's identity we can write:
$$
\exp\left( \Delta t (A + B) \right) \approx \exp\left( 0.5\Delta t A \right) \exp\left( \Delta t B \right) \exp\left(0.5 \Delta t A \right)
$$
and this is exactly the Leapfrog algorithm. I tried figuring out if things breakdown in 1D case of two particles going straight at each other. To do this I worked out the commutator term $[L_p,L_r]$ that comes up in [Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) formula. This also didn't help.

Anyone has a fresh look or has some derivations that go beyond basic 1D cases where things go nicely? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about your Hamiltonian? There are squares and a factor 1/2 missing in the kinetic part.

Comment: Yes. If velocities are relativistic ($v \to c$) then [kinetic energy no longer equals $\frac{p^2}{2m}$.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relmom.html#c4) This is the case of $m = 0$.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk This question should be asked on the physics-site.

Comment: Good point. [I mirrored it to over there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/455625/stability-criterion-for-leapfrog-in-relativistic-physics)

Comment: In the reference that you give it is stated that the method is globally stable, so why do you think that "stability should break down"?

Comment: What they refer to is that there is no energy drift. There should be issues stability issues when dt gets big - say for example that dt is bigger than distance between the particles. Then they can hop over each other.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by stability. Having particles hop over each other is unpleasant, but they may still be near the true trajectory.

Comment: On second thought: if you want to demonstrate that particles "hop over" why don;t you just run a single step with $\Delta t>>1$ you can calculate explicitly how large $\Delta t$ needs to be for the 1d case to hop over.

Comment: From my simulations I see energy (Hamiltonian) not being conserved. It's my understanding that leapfrog conserves the Hamiltonian only if its stable - meaning only if errors introduced by the simulation are small and don't damp out in time.

Comment: The exact claim, as can be found in the works of Hairer et al., is that the Verlet method in any of its implementation preserves to $O(Δt^4)$ an $O(Δt^2)$ modification of the Hamiltonian. This modification includes derivatives of the Hamiltonian, so that close to singular points of the Hamiltonian the $O(Δt^2)$ modification need not be small at all. // Of course this does not help if the Hamiltonian used is not even a first integral of the system.

Comment: @LutzL what is the title of the book/paper?

Comment: It is either the paper Hairer/Lubich/Wanner (2003) "Geometric numerical integration as illustrated by the Störmer/Verlet method", or the book Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner: "Solving ODE I: Nonstiff problems", 3rd ed. (2008), ch. II.16. Both should have almost the same information.

Comment: For $H=|p_1|+|p_2|+V(r_{12})$ I'd expect the ODE system to have the form $\dot x_1=H_{p_1}=\frac{p_1}{|p_1|}$ etc., which I do not see in the leapfrog equations.

Comment: $\hat{p_1} = \dfrac{p_1}{|p_1}$ so that exactly the equation. Anyhow, thanks for the reference, IMHO you can restate in again in an answer and I'd gladly give you the bounty.

Comment: I misread, I see now the scheme conserves phase space volume but not energy.  So are you trying to demonstrate that the scheme is not bounded in energy?

Comment: The way I understand this the scheme should conserve the H. But I am seeing the H not being conserved (in particular the $p$ part tends to become huge in one step). I am fairly convinced it happens when $x_1 - x_2$ is small (therefore the force so the rate of change of $p$ is huge). 

I am trying to demonstrate that one can expect no conservation of H in particular case of $r_{ij}$ being small.

Comment: I must note, I am not familiar with the "first integral of the system" methods.